# validation plugin is not validating regular expression in add method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've tried a basic regex validation using jquery validation plugin, but the thing is it is working only for the rules 'required' but not for the add method regexvalid. How to achieve this

Thanks in advance,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.mini.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("regexvalid",function(element,value){
            return this.optional(element)|| /[0-9]*/.test(value);

    });
            $('#logform').validate({
                rules: {
                    txtUsr: {
                        required: true,
                        regexvalid:true

                    },
                    txtPass: {
                        required: true

                    }

                },
                messages: {
                    txtUsr: {
                        required: 'Please enter username',
                        regexvalid:'valid numbers'
                    },
                    txtPass: {
                        required: 'Please enter password'
                    }
                }

            });


        });


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

.error

{

border-color:Red;

border-style:solid;

border-width:1px;

}

#signupForm label.error {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='LoginDiv' style='width:400px;height:300px;background-color:green;'>
    <form id='logform'>
        User Name : <input type="text" id='txtUsr' name='txtUsr' style='margin-top:12px'/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Password : <input type="text" id='txtPass' name='txtPass' /> 
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id='btnSubmit' value='Submit' />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect your regex to do?  In other words, what's the rule you're trying to create supposed to be testing?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

**1)**  The variables you pass into your custom method are *backwards*:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("regexvalid",function(element,value){
```

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), `value` comes first...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("regexvalid",function(value, element){
```

**2)**  I'm no expert with regex, *and you have not explained what it's supposed to do*, but it does not seem to be valid.  If you're wanting to test if the value is a number, use [the default `number` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number).  Otherwise, the `regexvalid` method itself is working and you just need to properly adjust your regex.

This is using the regex function from the default `number` method as a demonstration.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("regexvalid", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZFd4B/**

---

**EDIT, regarding your Regex**:

The reason your regex, `/[0-9]*/.test(value)` seems to do nothing is because it's actually doing nothing.

- `[0-9]` is matching any number.
- `*` is telling it to match "**zero or more**" of the preceding expression.

So thanks to `*`, the test will always return `true` regardless of `[0-9]`.

You never explained what this custom method is supposed to do, but the `regex` you provided is effectively moot, since it seems to be always satisfied for every condition.

Source:  http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#basics